# Populate RDLC using JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, rdlc

My current C# application is populating the RDLC reports using a locally hosted Database. 
But in the new version I have a web service that sends me Data in JSON string format, now how do i populate the JSON data in existing RDLC reports?

Any sort of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think the only solution is convert `JSON` to `DataTable` and use it as a `ReportDataSource`.

Comment: ok, but is there any other type of Reports in C# which can accept JSON and display it?

Comment: there's no direct report in C# yet that accepts JSON. I have no updates in SAP's crystal reports, anyone? anyway, if you really don't want to put time dealing with JSON to DataTable as mentioned by tezzo, then you have to convert your reports with jquery charts / reports. see some samples here http://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/

Comment: Thank you Tezzo, looks like your solution is the only best solution for my issue.